# Run a program before Logoff and wait for finish

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler, logoff

When I want to run a program (.exe \ .bat) before **Windows 7 Home Premium** Logoff \ Restart I use the *Task Scheduler* and I set a custom event: `Log:` System, `Source:` Winlogon, `Event ID:` 7002 \ 4634 \ 4647 \ .....

The problem is that the program starts but the system closes before the program finishes, while it's running.

What can I do? (My O.S doesn't have *gpedit.msc* unfortunately)

Comment: Perhaps give this a try (not sure if it'll work): Add `shutdown /a` to the start of the script (to abort the current shutdown), and then add `shutdown -s -t 00` to the end of it to initiate a new shutdown sequence when it's done. You may have to make a couple scripts or something to deal with reboot vs. shutdown vs. hibernation, etc.  Are you on an Active Directory domain by any chance?

Comment: It doesn't work. The system closes anyway. It doesn't abort the shutdown. The help says "/A can only be used during the time-out period"

Comment: What edition of Windows is this? Pro, something else?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium (no gpedit.msc unfortunately)

Comment: Could you have a shortcut to run this item , then use a shutdown command after, instead of fighting a closing down system to run a program then?   Just have an assortment of shutdown batches?  I use that method from toolbars (like docks)

Comment: No, I need to use the standard mode (standard UI) to restart and shutdown the PC.

Comment: Try make a batch file which executes the task and then, at the end, have a shutdown command.

Comment: No, I have to restart and shutdown the PC normally